# How to change the text displayed of Ember/Handlebars link-to?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, discourse

I am new to Ember (and Handlebars.js). The following code displays the word "Preferences" and it is a link:

```
<li>{{#link-to 'preferences'}}{{fa-icon "cog"}}{{i18n 'user.preferences'}}{{/link-to}}</li>
```

I realize that it is `{{i18n 'user.preferences'}}` that is displaying the text I want to change because I can remove it and insert plain text and it will display what I want. However, I want to understand where the text is coming from: a model, route, controller? This code is found in a user.hbs template.

Comment: check for a folder named locale in your app folders

Comment: bingo, that led me to client.en.yml which is housing all the text I was looking for...thank you!

Comment: It comes from a helper called `i18n`. Search the helper and read the code.